# Is there any way to write a case statement in SQL, if column A > 0 then column B, column C= 0

Tags: sql, case

I have multiple columns which have the same value and it is showing incorrect results when I summarize them. Is there any way to write a case statement in SQL, if column A > 0 then make all remaining columns be 0 (column B, column C, column D = 0) ?

If column B > 0, then make all remaining columns be 0 (column A, column C, column D = 0).

1st column gets the higher priority in this sequence.

[image]

[image]

I tried writing case statement but it did not work.

Comment: You will really need to provide an example of what you've already attempted, and where you believe it's not producing your expected results.  In reality, a CASE expression affects the output value of a single column only, so if you are looking to affect the output values of multiple columns, then your query is going to have to contain separate CASE expressions (with their own necessary criteria) for each output column

Comment: Got it. I'm writing case statement for each column. thank you!

Comment: Please replace the images with [tables](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277716/how-can-i-create-a-table-in-a-post). You are much less likely to get help if we have to retype the sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this example helps:

```
SELECT a
    ,CASE WHEN a > 0 THEN 0 ELSE b END AS b
    ,CASE WHEN a > 0 OR b > 0 THEN 0 ELSE c END AS c
    ,CASE WHEN a > 0 OR b > 0 OR c > 0 THEN 0 ELSE d END AS d
FROM tbl;
```